# sed: Replace char with string containig newline which is saved in a variable

Tags: bash, sed

Does anybody know, how this one-liner could work in the case the replacement is saved in a variable. The following replaces every b sucessfully by a NL:

```
echo "bbbb" | sed $'s/b/\\\n/g'
```

desired is sth. like this:

```
var="\\\n" ; echo "bbbb" | sed $'s/b/$var/g'
```

I get in the confilct, that I need double quotation for parsing the variables inside the pattern but I need single quotation for the $ to work properly interpreting the escaped sings as real instructions - as far as I see through.

thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
var=$'\\\n' ; echo "bbbb" | sed "s/b/$var/g"
```

This is, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the single quotes, but double ones:

```
var="\n"
echo "bbbb" | sed "s/b/$var/g"
```

Single quotes prevent the variable expansion